# MySQL: search by JSON attribute returns error

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column in MySQL 5.7 table with data type `json` and following values:

```
{"1": "test"}
{"2": [25,23], "3": [28,54], "71": "test"}
{"2": [25,12], "3": [28,72], "33": "test2"}
{"2": [25,11], "3": [28,23], "63": "test3"}
{"4": "test4"}
```

I need to query all rows with attribute "3" (regardless of value), so I'm making this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, '{"2"}');
```

I'm getting:

```
#3141 - Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Missing a colon after a name of object member." at position 5.
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT data->"$.2" AS myattr FROM `notes`;
#3143 - Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JSON_CONTAINS_PATH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains-path) since you don't care about the value

```
SELECT data 
  FROM notes 
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(data, 'one', '$."3"');
```

Sample output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| data                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| {"2": [25, 23], "3": [28, 54], "71": "test"}  |
| {"2": [25, 12], "3": [28, 72], "33": "test2"} |
| {"2": [25, 11], "3": [28, 23], "63": "test3"} |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```